# How to fix "Non-static method Spatie\Analytics\Analytics::fetchVisitorsAndPageViews() should not be called statically?"

Tags: laravel, google-analytics, laravel-5.5

When i put:

```
use Spatie\Analytics\Analytics;
```

It gives the error

> 'Non-static method should not be called statically'

But when I only put:

```
use Analytics;
```

I gives a white page on refresh or says

> "The use statement with non-compound name 'Analytics' has no effect "

when starting.

I am using Laravel 5.5.4 and although it says the facade should be automatically setup, it wasn't working so I also added this manually to the // config/app.php:

```
'Analytics' => Spatie\Analytics\AnalyticsFacade::class,
```

But it still is not working.

from the package github. there was a solution

```
php artisan config:clear
```

but it did not work for me.

Comment: have you tried composer dump-autoload after the installation of Analytics?

Comment: yes. but same issue persists.

Answer (score 4):

This package can be installed through Composer.

*`composer require spatie/laravel-analytics`*

In Laravel 5.5 and above the package will autoregister the service provider. In Laravel 5.4 you must install this service provider.

**config/app.php**

```
'providers' => [
    ...
    Spatie\Analytics\AnalyticsServiceProvider::class,
    ...
];
```

In Laravel 5.5 and above the package will autoregister the facade. In Laravel 5.4 you must install the facade manually.

**config/app.php**

```
'aliases' => [
    ...
    'Analytics' => Spatie\Analytics\AnalyticsFacade::class,
    ...
];
```

---

You want to use the facade to access the class, you will need to change:

`use Spatie\Analytics\Analytics;` to *`use Analytics;`*

Comment: i did all these things. unfortunately my problem still persists.

Answer (score 1):

Another way around just **import this to your class:**

```
use Spatie\Analytics\AnalyticsFacade as Analytics
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends in what context you place the `use` statement.

In Laravel you also can use facades without having to import it with `use`.
The same class can be called by using `\Analytics` in your code call.

Example:

`\Analytics::fetchMostVisitedPages(\Period::days(7));`

Answer (score 0):

for Laravel 10.

```
"spatie/laravel-analytics": "^5.0"
```

use `use Spatie\Analytics\Facades\Analytics;`